# Ionic: Get data from subscribe

Tags: angular, ionic2, subscribe

I am trying to get the data inside the subscribe. When I console log it inside the subscribe, the data is available. 
But when I try to store the data to a variable and console log it outside the subscribe, the data is undefined.

How can I get the result from the subscribe and store it in a variable?

I'm new to ionic and angular. :)
Thanks.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserServiceProvider {

    users: any;

constructor(public http: Http) {

}

loadUsers() {
   this.http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1")
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                //works fine
                console.log(data.results);

                this.users = data.results
            });

    //the variable is undefined.
    console.log(this.users);
  }
}
```

Comment: you already are storing in variable.. `Observables` are **asynchronous**. data is returned after you console logged your `users` variable`

Answer (score 0):

Your function executes console.log(this.users) first so it gives undefined because it does not get response and store it in data and assigned to your variable.

Try this:

```
loadUsers() {
   this.http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1")
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                //works fine
                console.log(data.results);

                this.users = data.results},

             () => {  console.log(this.users); } );

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are storing the data and the `users` variable already contains the needed `data.results` data. It is not the problem of ionic or angular.

It is simply subscribe is acting as an asynchronous function. The process is going on while you tried to print it. Hence the `undefined` error.

if you want to see the data right there at the same moment, do the following;

```
() => console.log(this.users)
```